# Find out the source repository that a docker image was pulled from

Tags: image, docker, registry

my understanding is that you can install a docker image from different repositories. No surprise there. What surprises me is that there isn't an easily accessible command that tells me that an image has been pulled from a certain registry i.e. some .

How do I get that information?

Answer (score -1):

Do not confuse repositories with registry.

A Docker repository is where you can store 1 or more versions of a specific Docker image.

This information for an image can be found by running

`docker images ls -a`

On the other hand a registry will consist of multiple repositories which contain images related to a specific project.

[Please see the difference here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/docker-hub-and-docker-registries-a-beginners-guide)

If you need to find which registry your docker instances is pointing to, run the below command

`docker info`

Comment: `docker info` does not have anything to do with the origin of one docker image.